# Prediction of vertex scores in a bipartite graphs

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, algorithms, graphical-model, graph-theory

I have a bipartite graph with two sets, ***A*** and ***M***, of nodes. Every vertex in ***M*** has a score associated with it. I have two tasks:

1. To every vertex *a* in ***A***, I have to assign a score based on the scores of vertices in ***M*** it is connected to, and
2. When a new vertex *m* is introduced in set ***M***, I have to assign it a score based on the score of the vertices in ***A*** it is connected to. (main task).

What would be the best way to accomplish both tasks so that the prediction of score of *m* is most accurate?

Edit: Think of ***M*** as a set of movies and ***A*** as actors. We have ratings of movies, and we want to estimate the ratings of a new movie. But this has to be accomplished based on the scores that we give to actors (based on the ratings of the movies they acted in) who worked in this new movie.

Comment: This is completely opaque to me. I doubt this can be answered based on what's here.

Comment: I have edited the question and have tried to give the context. Hopefully, it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple thing you could try is to think of each movie as a collection of actors, with each actor contributing some positive/negative rating to the movie. In other words each movie is a one-hot vector over all actors $1,2,\cdots,k$ giving you a binary vector $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)$. You then want some kind of multiclass regression, for example an ordered logistic regression which predicts movie score based on the actors in it. In other words for movie $i$, the score $s_i$ is modelled by:

$$s_i=Model(a_1\beta_1+\cdots+a_n\beta_n).$$

Then when a new movie comes out, you predict its score by plugging in its vector of actors.

Comment: There are two problems. First, I have millions of movies and actors, so running this type of a regression will be extremely difficult. Second, I have to use the setup I mentioned in the question (to make it fit the bigger picture that cannot be explained in the question). Do you have any suggestions how I can do this by first assigning the scores to actors based in existing movies and then using those scores to find the rating of new movies?

Comment: Kind of belief propagation, but I don't have a concrete idea.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The beta coefficients you get out of this model are *precisely* the scores you'd assign your actors which you can now use for prediction. You also don't need to train on everything all at once, since most actors only participate in a few dozen movies.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.

Comment: If you want something simpler, you could just average the ratings of each actors movies and use that as a baseline

Comment: I was wondering if I could simply use average of movie ratings as scores of actors, and then take a weighted average of actor scores to estimate the ratings of new movies. The question in that case is what will be a good heuristic way to find the weights. I just want a heuristic way, that is fast, not the actual way to learn these weights using linear regression.

Comment: @SonuKMishra: Right, you could then look at the correlation between average ratings and individual movie prediction. Keep in mind that most actors will have very few movies associated with them, so this will strongly pollute your estimates. I would start by just using actors who have a lot movies under their belt.